# .change() on an attribute value?

Tags: jquery

Is there a trigger within jQuery that will detect changes in attributes' values?

As an example:

`<div id="thisField" value-grabbed='1'></div>`

to

`<div id="thisField" value-grabbed='2'></div>`

and jQuery gives me an alert after the change saying "done."

EDIT----

I'll more than likely going to change the attributes' value using the `.attr()` code.

Comment: Your code is incorrect, don't make use of some custom attributes, use `data` attribute instead: `data-grabbed='1'`

Comment: How are you changing that data?

Comment: @roXon I had no idea that was a legitimate attribute. How come that's different? I'm interested in knowing!

Comment: @roXon I'd say incorrect is too strong. The page will be invalid "in the eyes of" HTML5, but it shall render just fine. It is really better to use `data-` attributes, though.

Comment: Just read about it here if anyone is curious: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: @acdcjunior yes, it's hard-worded, but we should all be evangelists of well-written-code, and use what technology and consortium gives us at disposition. That means It's not wrong to play with custom "attributes" **once the DOM is parsed** `8-D`

Comment: I totally agree with you @roXon. If it isn't well written, then I won't be happy. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however you have to create said trigger yourself.

```
$(element).attr("value-grabbed","2").trigger("attrchange");
```

You can automate it by overriding the attribute method:

```
(function($){ // avoid global conflicts
    var oldfn = $.fn.attr;

    $.fn.attr = function(){    
        var ret = oldfn.apply(this,arguments);
        if (arguments.length === 2 || typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
            this.trigger("attrchange");
        }            
        return ret;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I had a question. How would I be able to fire a `alert();` from this change?

Comment: `$(element).on("attrchange",function(){ alert("Worky!") });`

Comment: Thanks! I'll figure out why it's not working, it's probably something I'm doing wrong.